# WebView - Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow)

Tags: xcode, macos, webview

I create a new Xcode project from scratch and it compiles fine.

I add a label to the View Controller and this compiles / runs / shows fine.

I then drag in a WebView into the View Controller but get this message when I run the application:

```
Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow): *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (WebView)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Just Link Webkit.framework in general->Linked Framework and Libraries

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you need to define the Web view so it actually knows what todo all it is doing right now is trying to find what to run here, see a tutorial on youtube or such, this is the code i used for mine, just to set it up.
first you want to put the web view into the view controller and add a toolbar to the bottom of it.
add four bar button items onto the bar.
and put a fixed space in-between the two.

then you need to set the styles of them do this by going to attributes inspector> button type > choose style
choose the following for the button 1st one is rewind 2nd is forward 3rd one is refresh last one is Cancel.

then control click and drag the button to the web view it will give you the options for it like load rewind and refresh.

then go to your storyboard and make sure you have you main and header files connected do this by selected the view controller in the storyboard files, then
change the class to the view controller you want to hook up to.
then hit enter

go to your header file(.h) and insert the following code,

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

put it under the @interface with brackets but make sure that the code is not inside of the brackets.

then what you need to do is go to your main file(.m) and insert the following code like this

```
@interface WebViewController ()

@end

@implementation WebViewController


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil

{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        //custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {



    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; [_webView     loadRequest:requestURL];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

accept obviously you need to replace the void or just past into the right places
Then build and Run your code use iOS simulator iPhone 6.

Hope this helps have a nice day!

Comment: judging on the error text this is Mac App, not iOS (there is NSWindow)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the wrong property `webFrame` of `WebView` instead of **`mainFrame`**

```
if let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("index", withExtension: "html"){
    editorWebView.mainFrame.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are doing anything wrong. Its just a bug